# using keyboard to control the robot in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use keyboard to control my robot in gazebo. And I don't know which package should I use.
I install the "ros-indigo-key-teleop" but I don't find which node can I use.
Somebody can help? Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231265/using-keyboard-to-control-the-robot-in-gazebo./) by [littlestar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26326/littlestar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run
`rosrun key_teleop key_teleop.py key_vel:=cmd_vel`

I assum your robot alrd listened to `cmd_vel` topic to move. The key-teleop node is publising to `key_vel` topic by default so you need to remap to `cmd_vel`.

By the way, the value published by key-teleop is 0.8 when pressing up button, -0.5 when pressing down button, 1.0 rotation speed when pressing left/right button. So the motion might not be very smooth. You can take a look at another option which is turtle teleop (http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_teleop), some remapping is still needed though.

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [littlestar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26326/littlestar/) on 2016-04-14**:
It is work.Thank you!